# Why can not stop vsftpd server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, vsftpd

I am use Ubuntu Linux, and when I run command `netstat -lt`, then show:

```
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN
```

then I run command `sudo service vsftpd stop`, and run command `netstat -lt` again, the terminal will not show ftp server, but after a while, I am run command `netstat -lt` again, the terminal will show ftp server again:

```
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN
```

How strange it is!
How can I stop ftp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have another ftpd service.

Try with this:

```
# ps -ef | grep ftpd
```

And search for ftpd daemons.